# Need a tutorial or help on making a frame by frame splash screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I've been looking through questions and answers for this but found nothing that has helped. I have 13 png. images that I am trying to run one after the other in my splash screen. Here are the codes I'm working with.

splash.xml

```
<ImageView
android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:background="@drawable/logo" />
```

splash.java

```
public class Splash extends Activity{
Animation animation;
MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(7000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.thegoodwarren.lonte.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    StartAnimations();
}


private void StartAnimations() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Do your users a favour and don't put a splash screen in your app.  http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: What does this code currently do, and what do you want it to do? Would you narrow down what your problem is specifically?

Comment: Hi Halfer, currently the code(splash screen) opens to a png background and sound file. However, I want it to open to about 12 png files (one after the other) giving the appearance of an animated shot. It seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 13 png. images that I am trying to run one after the other in my splash screen.

Create an [`AnimationDrawable` in the form of an `<animation-list>` drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). List each PNG and the time that should be spent on that frame in the XML. Use that `AnimationDrawable` in your `ImageView`, and call `startAnimation()` on it to have it start animating.

Comment: @user2100950: If you click on the hyperlink in the answer, you will come to the documentation for `AnimationDrawable`, which shows the XML syntax to define one with your images, and shows you how to apply one. Note that you need to apply it to the *background* of the `ImageView` (there's a reason, though I forget what it is right now...). There is additional documentation on `AnimationDrawable` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: Okay so I put this code into my splash.java  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
  img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);
  AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
  frameAnimation.start();

Comment: But I'm getting  3 errors all saying spin_animation cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @user2100950: Did you create an XML file named `res/drawable/spin_animation.xml`?

Comment: Okay I just imported AnimationDrawable but I still have 2 errors saying  cannot be resolved or is not a field spin_animation. Please help?? Sorry!!

Comment: Oh!!! Okay so the XML file had to be named spin_animation. Let see what happens. One second!

Comment: But, what about the error on this line of code     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image) Do I have to create another xml??

Comment: @user2100950: `spinning_wheel_image` should be replaced by the ID of your `ImageView` widget in your layout. With respect to `spin_animation`, the filename must match the resource ID you use in `setBackgroundResource()`.

Comment: Could I send you a picture of the screen so you could better help me information wise? Because, as you guessed it I'm pretty new to java and xml.

Comment: @user2100950: I would recommend instead that you ask fresh StackOverflow questions, posting your problems (code, screenshots, whatever). To be honest, what you are trying to do is not what I would recommend starting with as a newcomer to Java, XML, and Android.

Comment: Okay well I've got everything in place for this code to work but I and still get this error on two of my lines                       ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);                     
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

Comment: Thanks fore trying to help I've rewards you the solution